# AngularDart: How to run locally release build

Tags: angular-dart

I made release build of AngularDart app with `webdev build`.

How can I run it locally before deploying to remote hosting server?

At the moment I am using [Built-in web server in PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php):

```sh
cd build
php -S localhost:8888
```

Is it possible to run locally release build with `webdev` or `build_runner` commands?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure!

```
webdev serve --release
```

or, if you want to run it with a specific build config, replace the `build` with `serve` in your `build_runner` command:

```
pub run build_runner serve -c production --release -o web:build
```

And if you want to get to it from somewhere other then localhost:

```
webdev serve --release --hostname 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: Thank you Brian! When using `webdev serve --release` I still see in Chrome console entry `INFO [app.main]: Environment: ServerEnvironmentId.development`. This is because the build settings `build.production.yaml` not used. Is there any way to provide build configuration similar to `pub run build_runner build --config production --release -o web:build`?

Comment: In `build.production.yaml`, which not used by `webdev serve --release`, I have `dart2js_args` option `- -DMC_ENVIRONMENT=production` which defines compile time environment variable to configure `routerProviders / routerProvidersHash` providers. I.e. to avoid hashes in production environment .)

Comment: `pub run build_runner serve -c production --release -o web:build` notice the `serve` instead of build after `build_runner`

Comment: Thank you Brian! `pub run build_runner serve -c production --release ...` running application in production environment, as expected .)